# C# StringWriter encoding issues

Tags: c#, asp.net, encoding

I'm using a StringWriter to construct a CSV from a GridView to email/output to the user, and I'm having some issues outputting the '£' (GBP) sign - currently when it reads it from the GridView, it reads it as `&#163;`, and this doesn't get encoded to the correct sign in the CSV. If I do a string replace of the ASCII code with the actual symbol, I get a little closer - the symbol appears but it also has an accented 'A' before the symbol.

Any ideas?

Comment: As a note any time you get that accented 'A' appearing is usually an encoding issue. That is often the first byte of an ascii character being represented as a multibyte character. In this case I suspect the string writer is using UTF8 or something and you are reading out in ascii or something along those lines. Always be careful of character encodings. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&#163;` is the HTML Character entity for `£`, so I don't know why a `StringWriter` would know about it.

You need to convert from HTML to text first, for example with [`HttpUtility.HtmlDecode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.htmldecode.aspx).